# MySQL Query not selecting correctly from 2 join tables

Tags: database, mysql

### Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2768 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `blogid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `islogo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=4132 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vdos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `blogid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `file` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `description` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=3759 ;
```

### Query

```
select distinct b.id from blogs b 
left join pics p ON b.id = p.blogid 
left join vdos v ON b.id = v.blogid 
where p.islogo = '0' and b.`active` = '1'
```

What I intend to do is to list blog ids that have pictures or videos. What this query is doing is that it only lists blogs that have pictures, and does not list blog ids that have only a video.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you shortening table names? 'pictures' and 'videos' are more clear to developers.

Comment: has your tables contain any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p.islogo is what's causing only blog with pictures. You'll have to do

```
where p.islogo = '0' and b.`active` = '1' or p.islogo IS NULL
```

To also match blogs without pictures.

Edit:
Sorry initially misread the question. The where clause should probably be changed to

```
WHERE (p.islogo = "0" AND p.id IS NOT NULL) OR (v.id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: `islogo tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',`

Comment: Even if it is defined as not null. If you are doing a LEFT JOIN from a blog with no pictures to the pictures table all the pictures fields will be null.

Comment: There's no change to the results

Answer (score 3):

That's because you set the condition that pics.islogo is '0'. It can never be '0' for blogs without pictures. Move the condition to the join:

```
select distinct b.id from blogs b 
left join pics p ON b.id = p.blogid and p.islogo = '0'
left join vdos v ON b.id = v.blogid
where b.`active` = '1'
```

Comment: For some reason, this is listing all rows

Comment: This returns all rows because there is no check on whether the selected blog actually has any pictures or videos.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. This joins all pictures and video's, but also returns rows with neither. You should add a condition to the where clause in my query: `and (p.blogid is not null or v.blogid is not null)`

Answer (score -1):

```
select from blogs b 
left join pics p ON b.id = p.blogid 
left join vdos v ON b.id = v.blogid 
where p.islogo = '0' and b.`active` = '1' GROUP BY b.id;
```